# Unable to find which files are consuming disk space in root partition

Tags: disk-usage, root-filesystem

When I try to display file usage on the root partition using an application like FileLight, it gives me this output:
[image]

However, I see different total usage in the Dolphin File Manager.
[image]

I got to see the same in the KDE partition manager and Gparted.
[image]

I am also sharing the output of the `df -hs /*` command. In the output, I see that the root and the home partition altogether consume around 45 GB s.

```
0       /afs
4.0K    /bin
455M    /boot
1.1M    /dev
42M     /etc
9.5G    /home
4.0K    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
0       /lost+found
191G    /media
0       /mnt
2.3G    /opt
du: cannot read directory '/proc/4632/task/4632/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/4632/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access '/proc/13575/task/13575/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13575/task/13575/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13575/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/13575/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       /proc
135M    /root
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
76G     /run
4.0K    /sbin
0       /srv
0       /sys
du: cannot access '/tmp/.mount_jetbrad4Z7Cb': Permission denied
52K     /tmp
17G     /usr
12G     /var
```

Please note that mount points of other hard drive partitions and Windows installation partition are mounted in the `/media` directory and the `/run` directory. That's why they are showing this usage.

Is there any other way to see what actually is consuming disk space in the root partition? I am seeking help for this.

Comment: Check your `/tmp/`.

Comment: Filesystem: btrfs. Compare to [*btrfs: browsing subvolumes*](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690), read my answer there. The point: "you should mount the root of your Btrfs filesystem somewhere, with `subvol=/ option`. This way you gain access to the filesystem in its entirety". Then you analyze usage, but there may be snapshots, reflinks. See [*Get size of btrfs directory which may contain subvolumes*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436585) and [*How to check (simulate), how much space will be freed after I remove a btrfs subvolume?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188315/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, so this is the mount point in `/etc/fstab`: `subvol=/@, compress`. Should I remove the @?

Comment: No. You should carefully read my answer to the question I linked to (the first link in my first comment).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I am not getting whatever you have written.

Comment: You should mount with `subvol=/` *somewhere*, but without touching what is mounted to your `/`. An example is `mount -o subvol=/ /dev/nvme1n1p4 /mnt/somewhere`. Then `/mnt/somewhere/@` will be your root subvolume (also mounted to `/`) and you shouldn't touch it recklessly, but `/mnt/somewhere/other_things` may be what takes disk space (and in general you shouldn't touch it recklessly either).